# Not able to get callback from notification click if it already running in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

if the app is already running I am not getting any callback on notification click. i am using firebase to send the notification.

I am using firebase to send notification. if the app is already running I am getting data from fcm and creating a notification. if I click on notification and app is already running in background. I am not getting any call-back to handle. it is working fine when I launch the app on notification click I tried to check onapplicationfocus for unity and also in manifest file by adding

```
<intent-filter> 
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> 
  <data android:host="CHANGE_THIS_DOMAIN.example.com" android:scheme="http"/> 
  <data android:host="CHANGE_THIS_DOMAIN.example.com" android:scheme="https"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

hoping it will control the click but nothing happens